# Binance API {"code":-1022,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."}. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, binance, binance-api-client

I'm not sure what is wrong with this code. I think I might be missing something somewhere but I can't figure it out. I keep getting the error. The keys are for the binance test net and so they aren't important.

```
const ts = Date.now()

var crypto = require('crypto')
                  , text = 'recvWindow=59999&timestamp=ts' 
                  , key = '<myApiSecret>'
                  , hash;

var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest('hex');


[hash, key, ts.toString()];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing wrong exactly, I'm not familiar with the `crypto` package you're using (maybe your secret is missing?), but here's an example of a correctly formatted request that fetches your trades in the BTC/USDT market

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("X-MBX-APIKEY", "...");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=500&timestamp=1642400013504&signature=...", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

---

I got this from using [binance's postman examples repo](https://github.com/binance/binance-api-postman) where they have a bunch of pre set-up [postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) HHTP request in postman, where you can enter your api details into an environment

[image]

and then open an example, and copy the relevant code in any language that you want

[image]

You have to link the environment you created to your example also, I don't remember the exact process, but I don't think it's difficult

---

You can also get around all the signature configuring by using [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt), it's kinda like an SDK with a unified response for requests to about 120 crypto exchanges. Here's how you would make a request with CCXT

```
const ccxt = require("ccxt");
const config = require("../config.json");
const binance = new ccxt.binance(config.binance);
// binance.verbose = true;
const trades = binance.fetch_my_trades("BTC/USDT");
console.log(trades)
```

CCXT also has a number of [examples](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/tree/master/examples) in the repo at the path `ccxt/examples`

---

P.S. Delete that Api Key, and get a new one. In the future just post your api key like `'...'` or `my_api_key` or something, as well as your secret and signature